# Django url by category slug

Tags: python, django

I need two ways to categorize my posts in Django.
First one is by School, and second one is by type of wellness(physical/mental etc)

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from PIL import Image

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'school'
        verbose_name_plural = 'schools'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class VideoPost(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.ForeignKey('School', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def _get_unique_slug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(VideoPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import VideoPost
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts = VideoPost.objects.order_by('-date_posted')
    return render(request, 'stories/browse.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, post_slug):
    # post = get_object_or_404(VideoPost, pk=pk)
    post = get_object_or_404(VideoPost, slug=post_slug)
    return render(request, 'stories/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.published_date = timezone.now()
                post.save()
                return render(request, 'stories/post_detail.html')
        else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'stories/post_new.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
## the way it is right now is displaying all posts no matter what category they are in
('post/', story_views.post_list, name='post_list'),

## I think this is how to categorize and sort them by category? but not working properly
# path('post/<slug:post_category>', story_views.post_list, name='post_list'),


('post/<slug:post_slug>/', story_views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
('post/new', story_views.post_new, name='post_new'),
```

in a template

```
//for A School
// It should link to Post lists that have "A" school category and its type of wellness
//something like

<a href="{% url 'post_list' A_School, Physical %}">
<a href="{% url 'post_list' A_School, Mental %}">

//for B School as well
<a href="{% url 'post_list' B_School, Physical %}">
<a href="{% url 'post_list' B_School, Mental %}">
```

I'm not sure if the question is clear enough.
What I'm stuck at is displaying the posts by its two different categories and linking it with template url pattern.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be readable, No need for explaination.

```
def post_list(request):
    category = request.GET.get('category', None)
    whatever = request.GET.get('whatever', None)

    posts = VideoPost.objects.all()

    if category: 
        # you can still use .order_by after .filter()
        posts.filter(category=category)

    if whatever:
        posts.filter(whatever=whatever)

    # do the rest of your logic here like the one above

    return render(request, 'stories/browse.html', {'posts': posts})
```

This assumes you're passing the category as a `query param`
*www.myexample.com/?category=myawesomecategory*

Comment: Thanks, but just wondering, just like I wrote on template, the url will be filtering by two types of categories, and to do so, wouldn't I need two more params on post_list?  Something like def post_list(request, category1, category2) ? Would reuqest.GET method do the job? I'm not sure.

Comment: including parameters in the function definition will make the url more complicated like `myurl.com/category1/category2` which is not practical, request.GET is what you want